# Stating a project as closed in github without deleting it

Tags: github, open-source

I've done several projects in my github while learning. Some of them are relevant, most of them aren't. In particular, I'm looking at [UserManager](https://github.com/FranciscoP/UserManager), one project that has been a long time with me but that now I consider it done (mostly for the lack of involment from me).

However, it has been a great learning experience and I'd like to still keep it while making sure that any visitor knows that it's a discontinued project. What's the best way of communicating this? How would you like to know that, when you enter a github project, it's been discontinued? Nowadays the best way a is a mix between the days of last commit / stars / etc.

I was going to just write **DISCONTINUED** on top of the readme.md, but wanted to know other programmers' opinion and whether there was a better way or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might make sense to add a *Current status:* line to the top of the project README, but I'd use terms like: *In development*, *Complete*, *Unsupported*, and *Obsolete*. "Closed" doesn't make a lot of sense since you can always pick up an old project and add to it, or someone else might pick up where you left off and add support for the latest OS version or whatever. I'd avoid "Discontinued" for much the same reason. The thing that (I think) you're trying to communicate to visitors is *your* level of interest/support in the project, so use words that relate that without discouraging others from contributing updates (unless that's really what you mean).

Comment: Well I wanted to share that the project is discontinued *for me*, but you're right, I didn't take into account that it's perfectly fine for me for anyone to pick it up, thanks (: